# Set Proxy on the Office and Automatic Outside

Tags: windows, proxy, laptop, users

I am in a situation where I need the computers to  use my proxy server for internet access but I still want laptops to be able to connect outside of the Office.
right now I push the proxy on the computers via GPO, works fine, but mobile users cannot connect to the Internet because of the proxy.

Any alternatives?
thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try doing a *transparent proxy*, which should not need any client side configuration and you can freely control who gets proxied and who does not at the firewall level. Alternatively, assuming that your mobile users are connected via WiFi, you may want to move the wireless network onto another network segment that by-passes the proxy.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a [Proxy Auto-Config](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) file.